# How do I solve the: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE error?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I was following some instructions from this [site][1]
After installing cuda veersion 10.0 on ubuntu 18.04 LTS and trying out the code, I got this error below.
I have tried reinstalling cuda and the drivers according to [this site][2]
but no  change in the error.
Still being new in gpu/nvidia/cuda stuff i'm not sure what could the the solution.
Please assist.
regards

ERROR:

```
    func2(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/dispatcher.py", line 42, in __call__
    return self.compiled(*args, **kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 799, in __call__
    kernel = self.specialize(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 810, in specialize
    kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 820, in compile
    cc = get_current_device().compute_capability
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/api.py", line 316, in get_current_device
    return current_context().device
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/devices.py", line 213, in get_context
    return _runtime.get_or_create_context(devnum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/devices.py", line 139, in get_or_create_context
    return self._get_or_create_context_uncached(devnum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/devices.py", line 152, in _get_or_create_context_uncached
    with driver.get_active_context() as ac:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py", line 387, in __enter__
    driver.cuCtxGetCurrent(byref(hctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py", line 274, in __getattr__
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py", line 234, in initialize
    raise CudaSupportError("Error at driver init: \n%s:" % e)
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init: 
[100] Call to cuInit results in CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE:
  [1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/
  [2]: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal
```

Comment: did you check if your card is supported?  is `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=` set to 0?

Comment: how would I check that ? i tried print (device_lib.list_local_devices()) but not showing GPU devices

Comment: this is what I get instead:[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 7644637117214659171
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3287840411102778088
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]

Comment: just echo it. should show a 0